# Why can't I use a function as key of a Map?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider two different function objects created by the same expression or declaration (i.e. by the same line of code). In this [example (which you can run)](https://runkit.com/thejohnfreeman/function-as-key-of-map), those functions are `wa` and `wb`, created by the same expression in the `wrap` function:

```
function a() { return "abc" }
function b() { return 123 }
function wrap(f) { return () => f() }
var wa = wrap(a)
var wb = wrap(b)
```

Any such two functions

- will not compare equal according to `===`,
- will not compare equal according to `Object.is`,
- but will be treated as equal keys by `Map`.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Key_equality):

> Key equality is based on the `sameValueZero` algorithm: `NaN` is considered the same as `NaN` (even though `NaN !== NaN`) and all other values are considered equal according to the semantics of the `===` operator.

You can read their definitions of [same-value-zero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value-zero_equality) and [same-value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value_equality) as well. By my reading, two different function objects should be two different keys.

(`Object`s exhibit the same behavior, but because they aren't meant to support keys that aren't strings or symbols, I am giving them a pass. I am tagging them because there is no tag for `Map`s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the Map key correctly - you're treating the Map as an ordinary object, and putting keys on an ordinary object results in the keys being cast to strings. So

```
var m = new Map()
m[wa] = "hello, world!"
m[wb]
```

coerces the `wa` and `wb` to strings (because object keys may only be strings), and the above code resolves to

```
var m = new Map()
m["() => f()"] = "hello, world!"
m["() => f()"]
```

To use the Map properly (so that it can have keys of *any type*, including functions and objects, that don't get coerced to strings), use `Map.set` and `Map.get` instead. Then, the behavior will be as expected - the two separate functions, not being `===` to each other, will have different keys in the Map:

```js
function a() { return "abc" }
function b() { return 123 }
function wrap(f) { return () => f() }
var wa = wrap(a)
var wb = wrap(b)


const m = new Map();
m.set(wa, 'Hello World');
console.log(m.get(wb)); // undefined; the map sees wa and wb as different, as expected
```

Comment: Getting `wa` wouldn't illustrate that the problem is fixed - trying to get `wb` and getting nothing in return shows that `wa` is not being seen by the Map as the same key as `wb`